# Create slider with initial value zero starts at middle and left/right side -ve and +ve values

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am looking for a solution to create a custom slider in Nativescript using Angular + Typescript.
The slider should be bi-directional meaning slider should have both -ve and +ve values, 0 starting at the middle of the slider as shown in below image.

[image: Slider Image].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Setting range in Slider with dual thumbs is supported if that works for you. Looking at the images, I don't think such behaviour is supported neither in iOS or Android. You will have to come up with your own Slider like component using drag events.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Yes, here dual thumb is not a solution. I will try creating own slider with gesture events.